# RowDefinition MinSize property Disappeared?

Tags: wpf, grid

A very weird situation...

Using the debugger in VS2010 I can look up a property MinSize of a RowDefinition which is defined on it's base class `DefinitionBase`. I can also ask for the value of this property in the immediate window. See the attached screendump.

BUT, when trying to use this property in code it gives an error stating:

```
'System.Windows.Controls.RowDefinition' does not contain a definition for 'MinSize' and no extension method 'MinSize' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.RowDefinition' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Also looking in [MSDN RowDefinition Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.rowdefinition.aspx) there is no such property as MinSize (also not on the [DefinitionBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.aspx)).

I feel pretty confused. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MinSize` appears to be [`internal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx) from here (notice the yellow icon in the lower left on top of the property icon), don't you want [`MinHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.rowdefinition.minheight.aspx)?

*(You do not see properties in the IDE that you cannot get or set, it would just be clutter, so you normally just see `public` ones and if you inherit from some class you also get the `protected` members)*

Comment: Ok. I can understand that. But how come that in the immediate window I can just "query" that internal value? And why does the documentation not mention this internal property. And about MinHeight -> it's not set (stays 0) after a call to Measure in code (I try to paginate large pages with grids into a fixed document and try to determine where to put the breaks using height information for the rows in this grid ;)

Comment: @JoepGreuter: For debugging it can be useful to know all the values so you get to mess with them. The documentation does not list them for the same reason they are not displayed in the IDE, they would just be clutter, also they are an implementation detail you should not rely on, they might as well be gone in the next version as they are not part of the public interface.